# Simply define an arbitrary, real function

Tags: function-construction

I know of a way to define an arbitrary function (say, a[x]) and then apply an assumption to it (say a[x] is real). My code is pasted below.

```
A[x_] = Function[x, a[x]]
Assumptions[A[x] ∈ Reals

Integrate[x A[x], {x, -1, 1}] // FullSimplify
```

> `0`

However, it gets very "messy". When I try to define operators on arbitrary functions, the output is, in example:

> `Function[x, a[x]]`

Instead of:

> `a[x]`

Is there a better way?

If what I just wrote above is not detailed enough, here is the exact code:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

(* -v - Arbitrary Real functions *)

α[x_] = Function[x, a[x]]
```

> `Function[x, a[x]]`

```
β[x_] = Function[x, b[x]];
γ[x_] = Function[x, cc[x]];
ρ[x_] = Function[x, r[x]];
f[n_, x_] = Function[{x, n}, ff[x, n]];
F[n_, x_, y_] = E^(I n y) f[n, x];

(* -^- Arbitrary Real function s*)

(* -v- Differential Operators *)

λn[n_, x_] = (α[x]*D[#, {x, 1}] + β[x] + n*ρ[x]) &;
μn[n_, x_] = (α[x]*D[#, {x, 1}] + γ[x] - n*ρ[x]) &;
Tp[x_, y_] = (E^(I y) (α[x]*D[#, {x, 1}] + β[x] - I ρ[x]*D[#, {y, 1}])) &;
Tm[x_, y_] = (-E^(-I y) (α[x]*D[#, {x, 1}] + γ[x] + I ρ[x]*D[#, {y, 1}])) &;
T0[y_] = (-I D[#, {y, 1}]) &;

( *-^- Differential Operators *)

(* -v- Assumptions *)

Assumptions[
  α[x] ∈ Reals, β[x] ∈ Reals, γ[x] ∈ Reals, ρ[x] ∈ Reals, F[n, x] ∈ Complexes];

(* -^- Assumptions *)

Tm[x, y][Tp[x, y][F[n, x, y]]] // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> -E^(-I y) Function[x, cc[x]] + Function[x, b[x]] Function[x, r[x]] + 
> E^(I n y) 
>   (-(Function[x, a[x]]^2 - Function[x, a[x]] Function[x, r[x]] + 
>      (1 + I) (1 + (1 + I) n) Function[x, r[x]]^2) Function[{x, n}, 0] + 
>    n (1 + n) Function[x, r[x]]^2 Function[{x, n}, ff[x, n]]) - 
> Function[x, 0] (Function[x, a[x]] + I Function[x, r[x]]) 
>   (1 + E^(I n y) ((1 - I) Function[{x, n}, 0] + n Function[{x, n}, ff[x, n]]))
> ```

Comment: I don't understand what `\[Alpha][x_] = Function[x, a[x]]` is supposed to represent. As a function, `Function[x, a[x]]` does not depend on `x`. For instance `\[Alpha][y][x]` and `\[Alpha][x][x]` give the same result. Perhaps `\[Alpha] = Function[x, a[x]]` or simply `\[Alpha] = a` would be closer to what you want?

Comment: `Assumptions[expr]` is a meaningless expression. `Assumptions` is the name of an option you can pass to certain functions: it has no defined behavior when used as if it is a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say "I know of a way to define an arbitrary function", but I wonder if you really do? I say this because you seem to have missed the most common way to do it — using [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) ( := ). For example, your function `λn` can more easily defined with

```
Clear[λn]
λn[f_, x_, n_] := a[x] D[f[x], {x, 1}] + b[x] + n  r[x]
```

and then

```
λn[y, x, 2]
```

gives

> `b[x] + 2 r[x] + a[x] y'[x]`
>   which is the behavior I think you are looking for.

Further, if you want to limit the kinds of arguments `λn` takes, you can write

```
Clear[λn]
λn[f_Symbol, x_Symbol, n_Integer] :=  a[x] D[f[x], {x, 1}] + b[x] + n  r[x]
```